# How to detect postProcess PrestaShop 1.6 EDIT/ADD/DELETE mode?

Tags: prestashop

How to detect postProcess PrestaShop 1.6 EDIT/ADD/DELETE mode?

I have code, something like this (detect edit not working...):

detect add - is ok
detect delete - is ok

```
<?php

public function postProcess()
{

    if (Tools::isSubmit('deletems_admin_delivery_manager') && Tools::getValue('id_ms_admin_delivery_manager') != '')
    {


        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('DETECT DELETE');


    } elseif (Tools::isSubmit('submitAdminDeliveryManager')) {



        if (!$id_ms_admin_delivery_manager = Tools::getValue('id_ms_admin_delivery_manager')) {

            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('DETECT ADD');


            // this not working...
        } elseif($id_ms_admin_delivery_manager = Tools::getValue('id_ms_admin_delivery_manager')) {

            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('DETECT EDIT - NOT WORKING');

        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace = by == in your last condition.

Of course, you don't really need the third condition:

```
$obj = $this->loadObject(true);
if (Tools::isSubmit('deletems_admin_delivery_manager') && $obj->id)
    {
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('DETECT DELETE');
    } elseif (Tools::isSubmit('submitAdminDeliveryManager')) {
        if (@$obj->id) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('DETECT EDIT');
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('DETECT ADD');
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

also you can use the Prestashop methods:

```
public function processDelete()
{
    //Delete
}
public function processSave()
{
    //Add or Update
}
public function processAdd()
{
    //Add
}
public function processUpdate()
{
    //Update
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Unfortunately, it still doesn't detect correctly.
As "edit" it detects "add". Editing mode is not detected

Comment: I noticed that "Tools :: getValue ('id_ms_admin_delivery_manager')" also doesn't work

The variable "id_ms_admin_delivery_manager" is when editing in the URL, then in postProcess it is no longer detected.
I can not deal with it :-(

Comment: I tried your code in various combinations, still without effects :-(
Adding, deleting - OK
Edit - does not detect or the detect same as adding. I don't know what I'm doing wrong 3 days I'm thinking about it :-)